# Set pyhthon env/version on Spark Worker server

Tags: python, apache-spark, ubuntu, pyspark

Hello I configured a Spark cluster, with a server as main and two others as workers, I wanted to add a third worker server, but I have an error

```
File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 690, in main
    % ("%d.%d" % sys.version_info[:2], version)
RuntimeError: Python in worker has different version 3.7 than that in driver 3.10, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions. Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.
```

I installed anaconda , and I created an environment with version 3.10,I added these lines to the bashrc file

```bash
export PYTHONPATH=/home/uskib/anaconda3/envs/python_spark_env/bin/python3.10
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/home/usakib/anaconda3/envs/python_spark_env/bin/python3.10
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/home/uskib/anaconda3/envs/python_spark_env/bin/python3.10
```

I Run the following command to activate the changes.

```bash
source ~/.bashrc
```

And i also set the spark-env.sh

```bash
PYSPARK_PYTHON=/home/uskib/anaconda3/envs/python_spark_env/bin/python3.10
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/home/uskib/anaconda3/envs/python_spark_env/bin/python3.10
PYTHONPATH=/home/uskib/anaconda3/envs/python_spark_env/bin/python3.10
```

But i still have the same error, any idea please ?
Thanks

Set python path of spark worker